# Maximum call stack is exceedeed

Tags: javascript

That's is my code, why I always got this Error?
There's no looping on my code.
Try to anothe browser, but I got the same result.

```
$(document).on('click', '#add_sup_btn', function() {
                var data = {
                    nama : document.getElementById("name_sup"),
                    alamat : document.getElementById("address_sup"),
                    phone : document.getElementById("phone_sup"),
                    email : document.getElementById("email_sup"),
                    name_pic : document.getElementById("name_pic"),
                    phone_pic : document.getElementById("phone_pic"),
                    email_pic : document.getElementById("email_pic")
                }
                sendData(data);
            });

        function sendData(param) {
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : 'upload/add_suplier',
                dataType : 'json',
                data : param,
                success  :function() {
                    $('#addSuplier').hide();
                    $('.modal-backdrop').hide();
                    console.log();
                },
                error : function() {
                    alert('Fail');
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Under what conditions does this code produce the error? It could simply be too many clicks!

Comment: A quick test get me no errors. Please provide more info.

Comment: Are those all the fields of a form? You could use `var data = $("#formid").serialize()` to get them all at once.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/javascript-get-input-text-value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to send DOM elements as a JSON request. DOM elements cannot be encoded this way, and if they could, would contain far too much information (width? height? event handlers? child and parent nodes? etc.). In fact, the specific error you get is probably caused by the recursive nesting of children pointing to parents and parents to children in the DOM tree.

Instead, use the `value` attribute (or whichever contains the actual information you want to send) in setting up `data`:

```
data.nama : document.getElementById("name_sup").value
```

for example.